# aygshell.dll missing on target device

Tags: c#, dll, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm developing a MP3 player for Windows CE using Compact Framework, but my target device does not contains aygshell.dll which, in turn, contains the [SndPlaySync](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/aygshell.SndPlaySync) function I want to use.

Looking [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/WinCE_Programming_Tips#Missing_aygshell.dll) I downloaded a ZIP contains some of this DLL, but neither of them export this function!

Where can I found the ORIGINAL DLL?

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to USS aygshell to play audio Giles. You van USS PlaySound or the wavwform audio api that is normally supporre ony ce devices that provvide an audio driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aygshell.dll can be included in a Windows CE 5-6/Windows Embedded Compact 7 OS image but, IIRC, it is not included in the core OS license that is what most of devices carry. If you can modify the image and its licensing, then you can add the DLL to your OS image by just selecting the aygshell component from the OS catalog.
The Windows CE version does not provided 100% of the features supported by the Windows Mobile one, it was originally provided to improve the app compatibility between the two OS.

Comment: Hi @valter-minute, thanks for your suggestions, but I don't want to deep into the OS image creation. As I said to josef, I think I will switch to some linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

You are lost. AYGSHELL.DLL is only part of Windows Mobile/Embedded Handheld/PocketPC but NOT on any Windows CE device. The build of Windows CE is totally free to the OEM. They can include/exclude whatever they want. Whereas Windows Mobile is a standardized platform where the OEMs must let there builds ceritify by MS.

You may look around for a windows ce port of ffmpeg/ffplay or similar open-source software. Possibly these will also fail as the device has to provide audio drivers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I will switch to some linux distribution ;)

Comment: Sorry but you provided wrong information here. Aygshell is available on ce and the is provides the waveform api and also directshow support for audio playback without requiring additional libs. Those features may not be part of the image, of course, but I've seen very few devices supporting audio hw and not the waveform api.

Comment: aygshell is PocketPC/Windows Mobile only. And if you have a Windows CE (not Windows Mobile, Pocket PC or Windows Embedded Handheld) it never has a windows mobile aygshell. Aygshell is provided only to OEMs building Windows Mobile images. Do not mix Windows Mobile OS (based on Windows CE) with a real Windows CE OS. Possibly an OEM placed some aygshell inside there OS build, but this is not the aygshell with SH... API standard functions provided by MS.

Comment: Aygshell version in Windows CE does not provide 100% of the WM features but provides a good subset of them (like right click support). Search SYSGEN_AYGSHELL in your Windows CE 6.0 catalog and be surprised.

Comment: Now, we talked about Windows CE 5 and NOT ce6. Windows Mobile and Embedded Handheld are based on WinCE5. As noted in the question, aygshell was not found on the device and so it seems to be a WinCE5 based device.

Comment: Your original answer states that no CE device can support aygshell and that was wrong. By the way, it's wrong also about CE 5.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927275.aspx

Comment: OK, I correct me: there may be Windows CE devices that include an aygshell.dll. But the decision is totally to the OEM.